# Trying to override getView in a SimpleCursorAdapter gives NullPointerExceptio

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Would very much appreciate any help or hint on were to go next.

I'm trying to change the content of a row in ListView programmatically. In one row there are 3 TextView and a ProgressBar. I want to animate the ProgressBar if the 'result' column of the current row is zero.

After reading some tutorials and docs, I came to the conclusion that LayoutInflater has to be used and `getView()` - overriden. Maybe I am wrong on this.

If I return  `row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);` from the function, it gives NullPointerException.

Here is the code:

```
    private final class mySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Cursor localCursor;
    private Context localContext;

    public mySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);            
        this.localCursor = c;
        this.localContext = context;

    }

    /**
     *    1. ListView asks adapter "give me a view" (getView) for each item of the list
     *    2. A new View is returned and displayed
     */
    public View getView(int position, View  convertView, ViewGroup  parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)localContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        String result = localCursor.getString(2);
        int resInt = Integer.parseInt(result);

        Log.d(TAG, "row " + row);

        // if 'result' column form the TABLE is 0, do something useful:
        if(resInt == 0) {           
            ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.update_progress);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);

            TextView edit1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_id);
            TextView edit2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.request);
            TextView edit3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.result);
            edit1.setText("1");
            edit2.setText("2");
            edit3.setText("3");
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);             
        }

        return row;
    }
```

here is the Stack Trace:

```
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:149)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at com.dhristov.test1.test1$mySimpleCursorAdapter.getView(test1.java:105)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1256)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1224)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1499)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-08 03:15:29.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(619):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have a *row.xml* in your `res/layout` folder? That might be where the `NullPointerException` is coming from.

Comment: yes, I have it, res/layout/row.xml

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For `CursorAdapter` and subclasses, you should override `newView()` and `bindView()` instead of `getView()`.

More importantly, though, you should not get calling `super.getView()`. That is where you are crashing.

Comment: Thank you! 
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
instead of 
View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
solves the NUllPointer problem!

Comment: @CommonsWare , How to ensure Row Recycling with CursorAdapter then?

Comment: @Droider: If you let `CursorAdapter` handle `newView()` for you, it will do the recycling.

Comment: But then , I get issue like images showing up with incorrect row. How to handle that?

Comment: @Droider: That is a problem with your implementation of `bindView()`. If you wish further assistance from somebody with regards to your problem, open up a new StackOverflow question and provide complete details.

Comment: @CommonsWare I already did , but got no assistance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040505/images-jumble-up-in-listview-using-asynctask and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046126/multi-threading-issues-during-image-loading

Comment: @CommonsWare 
i have prob with `newView` and `bindView` : http://stackoverflow.com/q/19226186/1318946

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `getView()` when extending the `SimpleCursorAdapter` class. All the functionality of `getView()` we get from the overriden `newView()` and `bindView()` methods.

```
if (convertview == null) // is equal to `newView()` and
if (convertview != null) // is equal to `bindView()`
```

One main difference is in `getView()`; we have the position as a parameter and in `simpleCursorAdapter` we get the position as `getPositionForView(view)`
view is a parameter of `bindView()`.

example: Mostly we are using `Listview` to put values...so you call `ListViewObj.getPositionForView(view)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should use a ViewBinder to achieve your custom binding. This way you do not have to override any code. Just make sure that you return **true** when you have set the value of the view otherwise the adapter will overwrite the value.

```
public void refresh() {
    Cursor cursor = ....get cursor....
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_SHORT_DESC}, 
            new int[] { R.id.icon, R.id.text1});
    adapter.setViewBinder(new ProductViewBinder());
    setAdapter(adapter);
}

private static class ProductViewBinder implements ViewBinder {

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (view instanceof ProgressBar) {
            String result = cursor.getString(2);
            Int resInt = Int.parseInt(result);

            if (resInt == 0) {
                ((ProgressBar)view).setIndeterminate(true);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```