# Populating single ListView with different row layouts

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview

I am attempting to populate a ListView with a column from a database. I can achieve this successfully, but the problem is i would like to use a different layout resource depending on if the id matches a PendingIntent.

This is to check if an alarm exists with the rowid, and i plan to have visual feedback in the listview to show the user which alarms exist. I can successfully check the rowid against PendingIntents and get a return boolean.

The issue I run into is populating the ListView with different layout resources for different rows (is this even possible?) and i have no idea where to go from here.

I currently have the following code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < numNotes; x++)   {

            if(existAlarm(intarray[x])){
                String[] from = new String[] { TodoDbAdapter.KEY_SUMMARY };
                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label1};
                cursor = dbHelper.fetchTodo(intarray[x]);

                SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.todo_row_green, cursor, from, to);
                setListAdapter(notes); 

            } else if (!existAlarm(intarray[x])){

                String[] from = new String[] { TodoDbAdapter.KEY_SUMMARY };
                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label};
                cursor = dbHelper.fetchTodo(intarray[x]);

                SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.todo_row, cursor, from, to);
                setListAdapter(notes); 
            }   

        }
```

But the ListView just shows the final database entry from the loop.

I would be very grateful for any guidance, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, only the last item will be shown. This is because you keep changing the list adapter each time you enter the loop and execute. Get rid of the loop.

If I understand correctly, you want to display a either a green row or not depending on the ToDo. If so, write your own list adapter which is a subclass of the SimpleCursorAdapter. Then override the `newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)` method to choose view to use to display the row. The `cursor` parameter is already moved to the correct position, so you can retrieve values from the DB for any necessary comparisons.

For example: I assume (because of the fetchTodo(intarray[x])) that you are comparing based on the id of the ToDo. In that case your code may look like:

```
 public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
      long id = cursor.getLong(TodoDbAdapter.ROW_ID_COLUMN);
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      if (existAlarm(id)){
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row_green, null);
      } else {
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_row, null);
      }
 }
```

I don't know if I understood your code well, but you can adapt this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite possible to use a different view in each row: you however can't use a standard SimpleCursorAdapter for it: you have to overload the getView() function. An example is at [Trying to override getView in a SimpleCursorAdapter gives NullPointerExceptio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398767/trying-to-override-getview-in-a-simplecursoradapter-gives-nullpointerexception) (there are a couple of errors which are answered in the post, but the basic technique is correct).

As far as showing only the last post, your code is creating a NEW SimpleCursorAdapter for every row, which is incorrect. You want to use the getView() override and then do the for loop and comparison in there.

Comment: You will also want to override [`getViewTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) and [`getItemViewType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) for the different view types that you use.