# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, listview

I am running the software but when i scroll with the listview, its showing ok, but after a while i get this error message:

I am trying to display a cursor to a listview.

My Adapter class:

```
  private class DBAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Cursor c;
        private Context context;
```

My Constructor

```
        public DBAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.c = c;
            this.context = context;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
```

getView Method

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null; 
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.match_item, null);
                holder.tvHome = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_home);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
                holder.tvHome.setText(c.getString(3)+"("+c.getString(6)+")");
                c.moveToNext();
                return convertView; 
        }
    }
```

Simple View Holder

```
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvHome;
    }
}
```

Adapter init

```
Cursor cur = dh.getAll();
    startManagingCursor(cur);

    String[] from = new String[] { "home" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ll_home};

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    DBAdapter matches = new DBAdapter(this,R.layout.match_item, cur, from, to);
    setListAdapter(matches);
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?I've searched everywhere but i could not find any solution

Best regards,
Nicos

Comment: could you show us the code where you instantiate this adapter?

Comment: @davogotland i edited my initial post. Adapter instantiation is included

Comment: i think c.moveToNext() in getView looks fishy. but i'm not sure.. what happens if you remove that?

Comment: oh, also: what class is the method getView in?

Comment: getView is in : public DBAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {

Also. When i remove the c.moveToNext() it shows the same info on all rows in listView.

Comment: did you try removing `c.moveToNext()` ?

Comment: yes. it shows the same data on all listview rows.

Comment: the adapter init code, is that inside a list view? what class and method is it inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're supposed to override `newView` and `bindView` when implementing your own cursor adapter, *not* `getView`. i found this: [Trying to override getView in a SimpleCursorAdapter gives NullPointerExceptio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398767/trying-to-override-getview-in-a-simplecursoradapter-gives-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.tvHome.setText(c.getString(3)+"("+c.getString(6)+")");
if(position<=c.getCount())         
   c.moveToNext();
return convertView;
```

Comment: won't this cause the cursor to move 2 steps every time around?

Comment: also, the if statement won't do anything, since it's followed by a semi colon

Comment: :) nice! but isn't the point of the cursor adapter that one doesn't have to do the moving? i thought it was done magically between the calls to getView? in that case, calling it explicitly would crash the whole thing.

Comment: @Nicos try again with this new version, and let us know!

Comment: 09-23 09:13:59.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 09:13:59.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(467): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 94 requested, with a size of 94
09-23 09:13:59.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(467):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)


The same error again

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only single element you have put index as 0.
You try  this one c.getString(0). I think it will work

Comment: one element was for demonstration. its actually 8 elements

Comment: try to read this one .This is easy example that uses database and also     cursoradapter .http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html