# Multi-threading issues during image loading

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my app , there is a `ListView` which uses a custom `CursorAdapter` to load data into it which is basically an `ImageView` and a `TextView` . I am loading images in an `AsyncTask` , now the problem is , initially all images are assigned to correct text , but when i scroll up and down quickly , it binds random image for each text . Since I am using CursorAdapter , I can't use `ViewHolder` here , so what shall i do to eliminate this problem?

Here is my sample code :

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
        String album_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        text.setText(title);
        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Integer.valueOf(album_id));
        new MyImageLoader(context,view).execute(uri);

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    private class MyImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap>{
        Context context;
        View view;


        MyImageLoader(Context context,View view){
            this.context = context;
            this.view = view;
        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... uri) {
            ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = res.openInputStream(uri[0]);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return artwork;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp){
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            if(bmp!=null)
                //iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, false));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED :**  I applied the setTag method , now the shuffling is less , however when I scroll fast the old image persists for a second until the correct image is loaded. Here is the new code :

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
        String album_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        text.setText(title);
        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Integer.valueOf(album_id));
// *****TAG SET*****
        iv.setTag(uri);
//***PASSING BOTH URI AND IMAGEVIEW TO CONSTRUCTOR***
        new MyImageLoader(context,view,iv,uri).execute(uri);

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        //v.setTag(R.id.imgIcon, v.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon));
        return v;
    }
    private class MyImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap>{
        Context context;
        View v;
        ImageView iv;
        Uri u;

        MyImageLoader(Context context,View v,ImageView iv,Uri u){
            this.context = context;
            this.v = v;
            this.iv = iv;   
            this.u = u;
        }
        @Override

        protected synchronized Bitmap doInBackground(Object... param) {
            ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                Uri uri= (Uri)param[0];
                in = res.openInputStream(uri);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            return artwork;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp){

            if(bmp!=null)
            {   ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                if(iv.getTag().toString().equals(u.toString()))
                    iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, false));
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE :** Setting a placeholder image before calling background task makes it much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that I have used is to attach the `Uri` to the `ImageView` via `setTag()`. Then, when you go to to update the `ImageView`, check to see whether the `Uri` of the image you are about to apply matches the value from `getTag()`. If it does, go ahead and update the `ImageView`. If it does not, the `ImageView` was recycled, and you can skip the update.

Another approach is to [use `setHasTransientState(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setHasTransientState%28boolean%29) on the `ImageView` (or perhaps on the row -- haven't tried this) when you decide you have a cache miss and need to kick off an `AsyncTask`. This will cause `AdapterView` to avoid recycling that row, until a matching `setHasTransientState(false)` call has been made. Chet Haase has [a DevBytes video on this](https://plus.google.com/108967384991768947849/posts/cEoMo5H9v5R), in the context of applying an animation to a `ListView` row and trying to avoid recycling problems. However, `setHasTransientState()` is new to API Level 16, so if you are trying to support Android 4.0 or older devices, this will not be an available option.

Comment: I will try the 1st method and get back. Cant try 2nd as I targetting API 15.

Comment: I am not able to understand where to add the tag , shall i create an `ImageView` object in `bindView()` and before calling `MyImageLoader` set its tag there and pass it as an argument to the constructor or to execute method?

Comment: @Droider: "shall i create an ImageView object in bindView()" -- you already have an `ImageView`. Call `findViewById()` to retrieve it.

Comment: Sorry I mean that only . I will retrieve it in bindView() , then setTag(uri) to it. And how do i pass it to MyImageLoader ? as an argument to constructor or execute method ?

Comment: @Droider: Your `MyImageLoader` already has the `ImageView`. See your `onPostExecute()`  method.

Comment: The issue still persists , however shuffling is less now. I have edited my post with an updated code. Please tell if I am doing something wrong

Comment: @Droider: "however when I scroll fast the old image persists for a second until the correct image is loaded" -- well, that is largely unavoidable. You have not downloaded the replacement yet. Another option is to set the `ImageView` to some placeholder image if you are kicking off a task to download its image.

Comment: But I am using :`android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

Using a default src. Shall i set image again ?

Comment: @Droider: Yes. Remember that the `ImageView` is being recycled.

Comment: But the question is where to set it ? Before kicking off my background task ? Because with parallel execution , nothing can be said about the order.

Comment: @Droider: "Before kicking off my background task ?" -- yes.

Comment: Do you have such similar issues(including this one) tackled in your book ? I would love to get one in that case.

Comment: @Droider: I cover lots of stuff, but this specific issue is not directly addressed. I've only written ~2,000 pages, after all... :-)