# When I check a RadioButton in one row in ListView with custom SimpleCursorAdapter, the other row is getting checked too

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

In each row of my `ListView` I have a `RadioGroup` with `RadioButton`s.

From the database I get five rows and when I check the RadioButtons in the first row and then scroll I see that the third row is getting checked too (on screen, not database).

When I check RadioButtons in the second row, the fourth row is getting checked too.

Screen placed a 1,5 rows.

```
public void bindView(View view, Context _context, Cursor _cursor) {

    String id=_cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    RadioButton RightRadio=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.RightRadio);
    RightRadio.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    RightRadio.setTag(id);

    RadioButton LeftRadio=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.LeftRadio);
    LeftRadio.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    LeftRadio.setTag(id);

    RadioButton UpRadio=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.UpRadio);
    UpRadio.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    UpRadio.setTag(id);

    RadioButton DownRadio=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.DownRadio);
    DownRadio.setOnClickListener(radioListener);
    DownRadio.setTag(id);

    int oper=getOperByid(id);

    switch (oper) {
        case 1:
            RightRadio.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 3:
            LeftRadio.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 4:
            UpRadio.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            DownRadio.setChecked(true);
            break;
     }

     if (portrait) {
         LeftRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         RightRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         UpRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         DownRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else {
         UpRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         DownRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         LeftRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         RightRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using getView() instead?

Comment: @joao2fast4u I read that for CursorAdapter should override bindView() for example here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398767/trying-to-override-getview-in-a-simplecursoradapter-gives-nullpointerexceptio

Comment: maybe you need to use default() in switch. just give a try.

Comment: @Umitk I try,with default, where all RadioButtons set unchecked. Then I can't setChecked on screen at all. Thank you

Comment: not set all unchecked. just do as default() break;

Comment: and also can you post your .xml for radio buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is some problem with the checkboxes and radiobuttons in gridview and listview,do it like this in your adapter,declare an arraylist to hold the checked positions of your radiobuttons

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

in adapter constructor:-

```
public YourAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mlist) 
{
......your other intializations;
for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) 
 {
 itemChecked.add(i, false/true);
 }
}
```

initialize as false or true depending on the value of the positions,and get the value in your bindview method as:-

```
radiobutton.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but as I write higher, for CursorAdapter should override bindView() instead getview()

Comment: sorry i was in hurry i have edited the answer if it has solved your problem please accept this answer

Comment: How can I get position in bindView? Thank you!

Comment: you can get the position using the method cursor.getPosition()

Comment: Now, checked radioButtons become unchecked after scroll, I try to use imageButtons instead radioButtons. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the switch mechanism this way:

```
    switch(oper) {
    case 1:
        if (checked)
            RightRadio.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case 2:
        if (checked)
            DownRadio.setChecked(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

For detailed demonstration and explanation see this: [Radio buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)