# setting listview selected items background color upon user selection

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I used SimpleCursorAdapter to populte a ListView with contacts names. 
In the listview.onItemClickListener I change the color of view's textview with the following code -

```
 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String a  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME ));
            Toast.makeText(contacts.this, "item clicked : \n"+ a + " " + Integer.toString(position) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextView tv =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

            tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        }
    });
```

thing is when color is changed for an item it also changes the item in the next page when user scroll the list.

Is there a getView method which I can override for the SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: I found an answer to my question in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398767/trying-to-override-getview-in-a-simplecursoradapter-gives-nullpointerexceptio)

Comment: Change the text color to default in getView()

Answer (score 0):

```
        private class ColorTestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            private final Context context;
            private final String[] values;

            public ColorTestAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
                super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
                this.context = context;
                this.values = values;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View layout_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                TextView tv = (TextView) layout_view.findViewById(R.id.list_textview);
                // Set text
                tv.setText(values[position]);
                // Set color depending on position
                int textColorId = R.color.black; // Default color
                if(position == 1){
                        textColorId = R.color.red; 
                 }

                }
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
                return layout_view;
            }
        }
```

In oncreate

```
    myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_listView);
        ColorTestAdapter adapter = new ColorTestAdapter(this,myLists);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```